# Python: How to find every possible combination of three elements taken together in n long list

Tags: python, list, combinations, permutation

We have a list `[a_1, a_2, a_3,..., a_n]` and we also have a function `f(x_1,x_2,x_3)`

What the function does is not important for my question.

In the function argument we need to input three elements from the list. We need to repeat the process until all possible picks of three elements are processed by the function, the order in which they are picked is irrelevant.

Example for 4 elements:

```
list = [a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4]
result = []
result.append(f(a_1, a_2, a_3))
result.append(f(a_1, a_2, a_4))
result.append(f(a_2, a_3, a_4))
result.append(f(a_4, a_3, a_1))
```

Only that now we have n number of elements. How to automatize the process for finding these combinations. We cannot use any fancy imports. We can only use Math and Random import, but nothing else.

Comment: OK, and did you try anything to start solving the problem? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: This is only the part of the problem I am trying to solve, this is also where I got stuck.

Comment: @Higs "We can only use Math and Random import"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def comb(m):
    l=m.copy()
    result = []
    while len(l)>3:
        for i in range(1,len(l)-1):
            for k in range(i+1, len(l)):
                result.append(f(l[0], l[i], l[k]))
        l=l[1:]
    result.append(f(l[0], l[1], l[2]))
    return result
```

Comment: Note that this will remove all but the last 2 items of the list passed as argument, which is probably not a very nice thing to do...

Answer (score 0):

When looking for combinations itertools can get the job done

```
lst=[i for i in range(1, 5)]

[1, 2, 3, 4]

[i for i in combinations(lst, 3)]
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: "We can only use Math and Random import"

Comment: I think this would also work with math.comb(n, k) in python right ?

Comment: @BiliDebili Have a look at the doc: "math.comb(n, k) Return the number of ways to choose k items from n items without repetition and without order.". So not at all what you want.

Comment: Whi not use itertools? It's a built-in library, and defining another function that does the same thing is, well, against what a library does.

Comment: I guess I can also use that, I thought it's an easier problem than it really is...